# How to replace/update an ActiveX control in a MFC dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, activex

I have an older MFC project build in VS 2003 that I want to port to VS 2010. The project uses an ActiveX control for grids, namely, VSFlexGrid7 from Component One. The problem is, that this version of the ActiveX control does not work in Windows 7 (which is what I have). There is a newer version of the grid, namely, VSFlexGrid8 which should be compatible with Windows 7.

The solution would be to replace all the older controls with the newer ones.

My question is, what would be the steps in replacing the controls, without touching other parts of the project. What is the simplest method to accomplish this? Do I have to modify classes, resource IDs, etc.?

[Solution: Replace CLSIDs in the .RC file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveX control is bound to the resource file via the guid that represents the control.  If you were to look inside the .rc file you will see the control with the associated guid.  In your case, it's probably best to completely remove the control from the dialog (using the resource editor) assuming that you can drag the newer version onto the same dialog.  Once you've done that, you'll  need to generate a new class wrapper for the control.  The class wizard should be able to handle that for you.  Once you've got a new class wrapper that represents the control, you'll need to replace the prior wrapper class in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the control is created somewhere in your dialog code with CreateInstance.
If the interface is compatible (I assume it is) , you just have to change the name or GUID that is used in the CreateInstance Code.

Comment: I do not have a CreateInstance in my code. I'm guessing the MFC takes care of this when the dialog is first created by calling the OnInitDialog() function.

Comment: How is this component created? Did you dragged it on the dialog resource. Afaik in this case the GUID of this component is inside the resource script.

Comment: Yes, it was created by adding an ActiveX control to the dialog resource. I'll try and change the ID in the .RC file and see how it works.

Comment: How to chang the class id of an existing activeX?